# Where can I find TikZ examples similar to this diagram?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I am trying to draw a figure with TikZ for my report.

Turns out it would be super beneficial, if I have can draw (and reproduce) something like this with TikZ.

However, it was hard for me to find a suitable example in TikZ example site.

Where can I find TikZ example similar to above figure?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The diagram is very simple to draw.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill=blue!10] (0,0) rectangle ++ (7,6);
 \path (4.6,4.8) node[draw,minimum width=2.8cm,minimum height=1.35cm] (r1) {}
  (11,3) node[minimum width=5.6cm,minimum height=2.7cm] (r2) {};
 \draw foreach \Anchor in {south west,north west,south east,north east}
  {(r1.\Anchor) -- (r2.\Anchor)};
 \node[draw,minimum width=5.6cm,minimum height=2.7cm,fill=blue!10] at (r2){}; 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, this seems a bit like an XY question to me. What you might be really after are the `3d` and `perspective` libraries, as well as the `tikz-3dplot` package. Now you could search for posts tagged with either of these, e.g. [questions tagged `tikz-3dplot`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tikz-3dplot).

Comment: Sorry for the obscurity in the question arisen from my poor understanding of TikZ ecosystem. I really appreciate your help for guiding me to look for more related resources :)

Comment: @shpark No worries! You're welcome!